# File downloads but while extracting it gives "invalid zip file"

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on a jsp zip file download ,I am able to download the file but while extracing I get Invalid zip file error. In the java controller I have added

```
 @RequestMapping("/upload")
public void getDownload(ModelView mv,HttpServletResponse response)
{
        String fileName = "";
            String fullZipFileName = zipDir+ zipFileName;
            
               FileManager fm = FileManager.getInstance();
            
             zipOS = fm.getZipOutputStream(fullZipFileName);            
                    
            try {​​​​​
            
               for(int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {​​​​​
                  fileName = (String) selectedFiles.get(i);
            
                  File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                  
                  bIS = fm.getBufferedInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
                 
                  ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                  zipOS.putNextEntry(entry);
            
                  while((count = bIS.read(fileToAddToZip, 0, buffer)) != -1) {​​​​​
                     zipOS.write(fileToAddToZip, 0, count);
                  }​​​​​
                  bIS.close();
               }​​​​​
               zipOS.close();
        
        FileManager fm = FileManager.getInstance();
        bIS = fm.getBufferedInputStream(zipFileName);
        
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bIS.available()];
        bIS.read(byteArray);
        bIS.close();
           
    response.setContentType("application/octate-stream");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename" + zippedFilename);    
    response.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);
}
```

In the jsp side I have added

```
    $.ajax({​​​​​​​​​​​
        type: 'POST',
        url: "${​​​​​​​​​​​pageContext.request.contextPath}​​​​​​​​​​​/download",
       
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        success: function (res, textStatus, response) {​​​​​​​​​​​
            var fileName = response.getResponseHeader("content-disposition").replace("attachment;filename=", "");
var fileName = response.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition").replace("attachment;filename=", "");

      var bytes = new Uint8Array(res.length);
      for(var i=0;i< res.length;i++)
      {
      var as=res.charCodeAt(i);
      bytes[i]=as;
       }

            var blob = new Blob([bytes], {​​​​​​​​​​​ type: "application/octetstream" }​​​​​​​​​​​);
    
            //Check the Browser type and download the File.
    
            var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
    
            if (isIE) {​​​​​​​​​​​
    
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    
            }​​​​​​​​​​​ else {​​​​​​​​​​​
    
                var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    
                link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
    
                var a = $("<a />");
    
                                    a.attr("download", fileName);
    
                a.attr("href", link);
    
                $("body").append(a);
    
                a[0].click();
    
                $("body").remove(a);
    
            }​​​​​​​​​​​
    
        }​​​​​​​​​​​,
        error: function (e) {​​​​​​​​​​​
           
        }​​​​​​​​​​​
    
    }​​​​​​​​​​​);
```

I am able to download the file but when I try to extract the zip file ,I get Invalid zip file. Can someone tell me how can I fix this issue

Comment: Does the content of the file look like a zip file if you open it with a text editor?

Comment: You should first narrow down the error. There are three layers: controller, web tier, HTML/JavaScript. First in the controller write the generated bytes to a file and check if it is ok. If it is ok use a tool like curl or postman to call the URL to download the ZIP file. After that you know in which part the error is and you can debug further.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes in the browser it appears as a zip file

Comment: Write your zip file directly to file on server side and check if it is a valid zip file.

Comment: @Antonioss before converting the zip file into byte[] , we will create a zip file in another location and that zip file is valid one, I am able to extract it

Comment: @vanje The zip file is valid

Comment: `application/octate-stream` ->a typo in `octete` and another one `application/octetstream`

Comment: @Antoniossss still the same issue

Comment: @Thejas: This is nice. Did you do all what I suggested? What is your conclusion?

Comment: @vanje In the java controller I did a file write and was able to get a zip file and was able to extract the contents as well

Comment: @Thejas: We can not debug your code for you. You have to do this on your own.  We can give you hints and suggestions but if you don't want to follow them you are on your own. If you had followed my suggestions completely, you would now at least know in which part of your application the error is to be located. (This is some form of divide and conquer.)

Comment: @vanje okay I have tried the controller side, let me check the curl or postman

Comment: @vanje In the postman I got the response and saved the response to a zip file and was able to get the valid zip file

Comment: Great. Now you know the server code works. Then you can concentrate on debugging your JavaScript code.